# Biostatistics - Using mean and standard deviation to calculate probability

Tags: statistics

The common fruit fly, Drosophila melanogaster, is the most studied organism in genetic
research because it is small, easy to grow and reproduces rapidly. The length of the thorax
(where the wings and legs attach) in a population of male fruit flies is approximately Normally
distributed with mean 0.810 millimeters (mm) and standard deviation 0.075 mm.
 Choose a male fruit fly at random. What is the probability that the fly you choose has a
thorax longer than 0.9mm?

Comment: Welcome to stackexchange. This is a standard problem in elementary statistics. What have you tried and where are you stuck? Unless you tell us that (by editing the question) you're likely to accumulate downvotes and votes to close rather than an answer.

Answer (score 0):

You have $X \sim \mathsf{Norm}(\mu = 0.810, \sigma = 0.075)$ and you seek
$P(X > .9) = 1 - P(X \le .9).$ Standardize using the known $\mu$ and $\sigma.$ Then use
printed normal tables (or available software) to find the probability.
It's late here; if I made no typos, you should get somewhere between 0.11 and o.12.